# Calculate Average Time between columns of two different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `event` and `trans`.

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `event_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE `trans` (
  `item_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp
)
```

Assume Values for **event** table(multiple user visits):

```
|visit |a1 |2016-09-14 22:48:14 |
|visit |a2 |2016-09-14 22:48:28 |
|visit |a3 |2016-09-14 22:48:45 |
|visit |a1 |2016-09-15 15:10:39 |
|visit |a2 |2016-09-15 15:11:08 |
|visit |a1 |2016-09-15 15:12:34 |
```

and for **trans** table

```
|i1 |1 |100 |a1 |2016-09-15 15:12:22 |
|i2 |2 |100 |a2 |2016-09-15 15:13:17 |
|j1 |1 |140 |a1 |2016-09-15 16:12:22 |
|j4 |3 |150 |a3 |2016-09-15 16:13:17 |
```

I am trying to find average time between first visit and first purchase across users.

```
SELECT trans.user_id , event.time, trans.time as TransTime, AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(second,event.time,trans.time))
FROM event JOIN trans
ON trans.user_id = event.user_id and event.time < trans.time
GROUP BY trans.user_id;
```

I am feeling like I am missing something here. Will this always pick first visit and first transaction?
And also how do I get first visit and purchase?

Comment: IF you can provide expected result then it will be more clear for we all to workout on the question.

Comment: @Suraz I am trying to find 1. avg time b/w first visit and first purchase and 2. avg time between visit and purchase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest aggregating the tables before joining them:

```
select avg(timestampdiff(second, e.mintime, t.mintime))
from (select user_id, min(time) as mintime
      from event e
      group by user_id
     ) e join
     (select user_id, min(time) as mintime
      from trans t
      group by user_id
     ) t
     on e.user_id = t.user_id;
```

Comment: I hope you meant `on e.user_id = t.user_id`

Comment: thanks! coming to the second question, how can I capture a visit event followed by transaction?

Comment: @SunilBN . . . That sounds like a different question.  You should ask another question, with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, requirement changed and I was able to solve the use case based on this answer itself.